# Getting undefined values when I try to call property of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-realm

I am trying to access property values of a mongoDB Atlas document within a mongoDB Realm HTTP function.

The document within the mongoDB collection looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60dd5a9da81cb4304a8992fe"
  },
  "name": "testName",
  "reviews": [
    {
      "date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1624924800000"
        }
      },
      "stars": {
        "$numberInt": "1"
      },
      "review": "Test"
    },
    {
      "date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1625183486238"
        }
      },
      "stars": {
        "$numberInt": "3"
      },
      "review": "testReview"
    }
  ],
  "stars": {
    "$numberDouble": "2.0"
  }
}
```

This is written in MongoDB Realm.

```
exports = function(payload, response) {
    const collection = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("info").collection("landlords"); // get landlords collection
    const query = {"_id":new BSON.ObjectId(payload.query._id)}; // set up query for search
    const landlord = collection.findOne(query); // finds object with corresponding id
    return landlord.stars; // should return the stars value in the object
```

However, the output looks like this when I run it:

```
> result (JavaScript): 
EJSON.parse('{"$undefined":true}')
```

I'm looking for it to return the value of the stars property. Which in this case is 3.

I have tried calling the property value with `landlord["stars"]` but I get the same response. When I return the `typeof` the landlord document it says that it is indeed an object. However for whatever reason when I try to access the property values it returns as undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, needed to make it an asynchronous function. This now works

```
exports = async function(payload, response) {
    const collection = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("info").collection("landlords"); // get landlords collection
    const query = {"_id":new BSON.ObjectId(payload.query._id)}; // set up query for search
    const landlord = await collection.findOne(query); // finds object with corresponding id
    return landlord.stars; // returns the stars value in the object
```

Comment: I get a Value is undefined when trying to call  "new BSON.ObjectId()"